# Git deployment outside of heroku

Tags: git, tomcat, deployment, heroku

I like very much the way applications are deployed at heroku by just pushing in git. Is there a way to use such kind of deployment in Java?

P.S. I have a small application which is deployed to tomcat server. I don't need distribution and other stuff.

Comment: I would guess that if you control the server you deploy to, you could implement the deploy-functionality using post-receive githooks on the receiving end (on the server), and then just `git push` to the server, just like on heroku.

Comment: @Frost I want a ready to use solutions. I just don't have time to hack with scripts myself. I bet, someone solved this issue before me.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov - as others are suggesting, a post-receive hook can do this simply. Use it to call your *existing* build scripts to build the new code as a war (or whatever applies).

PS: Downvoting others because you do not *like* their answers is bad form. I suggest just not upvoting them if you do not like them.

Comment: @elithrar Post recieve hook isn't what I need. They run on my computer, I need them to run on the server. Now, when I deploy to the tomcat, tomcat watches the directory with wars and if it changes, it redeploys the application. I want some utility which does the same with git repo.

Comment: @elithrar IMHO, answering a question without understanding it (probably just to improve their rating), like some people I downvoted done, is a good reason to downvote. One of them suggested me to use build tool the other one suggested to use build server, whereas I wanted specific behavior available in commercial tools.

Comment: @KonstantinSolomatov Your original question is incredibly vague and did not clarify those issues (and still does not). You should edit it to address a) Whether you compiling the war file *prior* to pushing it via `git`, and b) if not, *how* it is being compiled (if at all?) on the remote side, so that Tomcat can detect the updated war and re-deploy it.

Comment: @elithar Have you ever used heroku? If not, it's better to take a look at it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Comment: I use it regularly, and am well aware of how it handles deployment on a push—and the answer is via some clever post-receive hooks. If you cannot answer the two questions I posed above I'm not sure anyone can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Java is a compiled language, you don't have the same luxury as ruby and other languages where you simply deploy code.

Take a look at AppHarbour as they do this for C# and from there see if anyone is offering the same thing for Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with this software you can make a **git pull** then **build** your **war** file and its possible to extend the system and execute a script that copy the file over ssh to your server for example and restart your tomcat.

in Jenkins you have a lot of Plugins.

There are some other deployment softwares but all of them cost a lot of money.

Comment: I understand how this can be done. I just want a ready solution. I want to run some kind of daemon which will look for changes in git, and build and deploy project to a war directory on the server.

Comment: This is not possible. You should do it on your own. But i think you know when you have made a change and can start Jenkins. Other Solution is to build a hook. But then you have to script it.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to build automation DSLs such as [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) , [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/).
You will have probably to automate the deployment process under your environment.

The first objective you should follow is to set up a build automation system that allows you to 1-click-deploy (or 1-command-deploy)

The successive step you achieve is a [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) system.

Comment: I have continuous integration. I just want a way to control deployment in a way similar to heroku's